# Get dynamic month(column name) which needs to be updated

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a query which gives me some data. I have `12 months` say. but it will update the data for the column say `month12` *(because current month is december)*

there are `12 columns` based on each month. here is my query,

In my select query I need to find which month's columns needs to be updated.

Below is my query

```
select  --a.emp_mkey,
                                @Total_day =  Sum(total_day), 
                                @Days_worked = Sum(days_worked)       
                                from emp_mon_day a      
                                where a.emp_mkey =  @emp_card_no
                                and a.month = @actualMonth and Year = @actualYear 
                            group by emp_mkey       

                            if(@Days_worked > 0)
                             BEGIN
                                set @actualleavedays =((1.75) / @Total_day) * (@Days_worked)
                             END 
                        print @actualleavedays
```

I am using `SQL - server 2005`

**UPDATE**

so what month will come here  -- month1, month2, ...... ???

```
-- update p_leave_allocation_14122015 a
                    --      set a.month1 = 8.18
                    -- where year = a.actualYear and a.emp_card_no = @emp_card_no
```

Do let me know if you want to view whole procedure.

Comment: you can use dynamic sql statement 
Declare @sql
 = 'Update x set Month' +Convert(Nvarchar,DATEPART(mm,GETDATE())) + '=?  ...............'
exec

Comment: @AhmedGalal: i have declared all 12 months in the declare area, but for getting it dynamically what shd I do please ellaborate.

Comment: generate your sql command as string and execute it

Comment: which sql command you are talking about ?? I need dynamic month here ?

Comment: you can get dynamic month from current date DATEPART(mm,GETDATE())

Comment: can u adjust in my `Update` query and let me know how to do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98537/discussion-between-ahmed-galal-and-coder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic sql and generate your command as string and execute it 
example:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(250)
SET @sql ='Update MyTable Set  columnName'+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),DATEPART(mm,GETDATE())) + '=value '
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: will it give me the exact column(month) which needs to be added